# How to measure the impact on my homepage load time of each snippet/tag called by GTM?

Tags: performance

The tool I am using to measure the load time of my homepage, show the load time for GTM, but I do not have more details.

I would like to know in how much each of the snippets and events inside Google Tag Manager are impacting my page load time.

Do you know any tool or any way to know this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the developers console network tab or something like Webpagetest.org to see when and how long is taking each element to load.